# I am having error in the code for deletion i have unlinked the file but data from database is not deleted

Tags: php, mysqli

```
public function deleteuser()
{

    $this->sql = " SELECT admin_img FROM admin_data WHERE admin_id = '$this->admin_id' ";
        $this->res = mysqli_query($this->conxn, $this->sql) 
            or trigger_error($this->err = mysqli_error($this->conxn));
        $this->numRows = mysqli_num_rows($this->res);
        $this->data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($this->res);

        //filename
        $file_name = $this->data['admin_img'];


        $destination="Uploads/".$file_name;


        //delete the file
        if(file_exists($destination)){


                if(unlink($destination)){
            //file removed from the server
            //now remove from the database
                    $this->sql = " DELETE FROM admin_data WHERE admin_id = '$this->admin_id' ";
                    $this->res = mysqli_query($this->conxn, $this->sql)
                    or trigger_error($this->err = mysqli_error($this->conxn));
                    $this->affRows = mysqli_affected_rows($this->conxn);
                    echo $this->affRows;

                    if($this->affRows>0){

                    return TRUE;
                    }
                    else{
                        return FALSE;
                    }



                else{
                     return FALSE;
                }
        }//delete file ends
```

I have unlinked the file which i uploaded but i can remove the data which i stored while adding the user with file.
I am not getting any errors too but the code is always **returning False**
I want the code to return true value.

**Please help me **
**Thanks in advance**

Comment: check **WHICH** if your falses is failing. you've got 2 there, and are just assuming it's the inner one.  maybe it's the outer one, which means it's the unlink which fails.

Comment: Unlink works and the file is removed from directory but after unlink the sql statement doesnot works i have tried using echo inside the if(unlink) echo is displayed but sql code doesnot delete the data from database

Comment: Your $destination is a relative path. Not a good plan for constant behavior.

Comment: Have you taken your echoed sql statement and manually ran it to see if you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

try this in your unlink if condition

while unlinking you need to give your root path

```
if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$destination)){
  if(unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$destination)){

  //your delete code
  }
}
```

Comment: file is deleted but my  $this->sql = " DELETE FROM admin_data WHERE admin_id = '$this->admin_id' "; code is not working

Comment: you said that "the code is always returning False" so the unlink condition fails.

Comment: no unlink condition doesnot fail but my sql is not working